# The group of upper triangular matrices in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given the subgroup $H\leq GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ the set of upper triangular matrices, I want to show that $H$ is not nilpotent.

The first part of the problem is showing $H$ is solvable. Define $G_1 = H$, $G_2=[G_1, G_1]$, and $G_{i+1} = [G_i, G_i]$, $H$ is solvable if at some point we have $G_N = \{id\}$. We see that $G_2 = SL_n(\mathbb{R})$, in $G_3$ the matrices have $1$'s on the diagonal, for each step after, one further upper diagonal will become zero and we have $G_{n+2} = \{id\}$.

Using the similar definition for nilpotent, define  $G_1 = H$, $G_2=[G_1, G_1]$, and $G_{i+1} = [G_1, G_i]$  we need $G_N = \{id\}$. But in general, I don't quite see what $[G_1, G_i]$ looks like except $i=1$.

I also have another definition for nilpotent, that is, going from below from $G_1 = {id}, G_2 = Z(H)$, and $G_{i+1}$ is chosen such that $G_{i+1}/G_i = Z(H/G_i)$, $H$ is nilpotent if at some point, we have $G_N = H$.

Note: $[X,Y]$ is the commutator group generated by $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ for all $x,\in X, y\in Y$. $Z(G)$ is the center of a group $G$.

**I posted my answer below, could someone give me some feedback, I am not sure if it is correct.**

Comment: Why the first part is to show $\;H\;$ is solvable? What do we care about that? We indeed have that any nilpotent group is solvable, so from showing the latter the former doesn't follow... *unless* there's some key idea used in showing solvability that can help us.

Comment: @DonAntonio showing it is solvable was first part of the problem, I thought it might give me some insight about how to argue for the second part.

Comment: @Xi Ok, I see. You may be right

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it.

First Note that $Z(H)$ are only the scaler matrices.

We use the second definition for nilpotent, given $G_1 = \{id\}, G_2=Z(H)$ we show that $G_3 = Z(H)$ then by induction, all $G_n = Z(H)$ so the sequence $G_n$ will never reach $H$.

From $G_3/Z(H) =  Z(H/Z(H))$, suppose given $bZ(H)\in G_3/Z(H)$, then we have
$$bZ(H)hZ(H) =hZ(H)bZ(H) \quad \text{ for all $h \in H$}   $$
the above implies
$$bhZ(H) = hbZ(H) \quad \text{ for all $h \in H$} $$
then $b$ has to be a scaler matrix.